# input box finds and opens folder in windows explorer

Tags: windows, input, directory

The problem:

I have 10,000 numbered folders. for example:

root/7000-8000/7400/7473/

root/3000-4000/3800/3846/

These network folders are "unit folders" that contain all the documents, design, photos, accounting, etc data for each "unit" that my company sells.  These documents are organized by subdirectory. Dozens of employees refer to these folders hundreds of times per day.  It is tedious to constantly drill down to the folder you are looking for.

What I want:

I want to create a simple input box, where the user only has to enter in a unit number, lets say between 1 and 100,000, and press enter.  The system will automatically open up the corresponding "unit folder".

How:

I am looking for someone to help me figure out which scripting language I need to learn to get this done, which functions in particular I should look into, and any deal-breakers I should know about.

I need some sort of input box, the simpler the better, that can stay on the desktop or in the taskbar. Next I need to parse the input digits, and break them down into thousands, hundreds, tens, etc.  Then I need to assemble those variables into a target folder, to create the correct command to send to explorer. lastly I need to issue an error if something went wrong.

Thanks in advance for any advise!

Answer (score 0):

We got it figured out.  The code is attached below if anyone else comes across something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Function CheckPath(strPath As String) As Boolean
        Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

        If fso.FolderExists(strPath) Then
            CheckPath = True
        Else
            CheckPath = False
        End If
End Function

''''''''''''''''''
Private Sub cmdGo_Click()
Dim unit As Double 'unit number
Dim unitTh As Integer 'for thousand of unit
Dim unitHu As Integer 'for hundred of unit
Dim locationstring As String 'for string to store folder location
Dim Exists As Boolean 'ensure folder exists

locationstring = "Z:\Unit Folders\"
If Val(txtUnit.Text) > 90000 Then
    unit = Val(txtUnit.Text) - 90000
    unitHu = Fix(unit / 100)

    locationstring = locationstring & "RTB90000-90999\RTB"
    locationstring = locationstring & "90" & unitHu & "00"
    locationstring = locationstring & "\RTB90" & unit & "\"
Else
    unit = Val(txtUnit.Text)
    unitTh = Fix(unit / 1000)
    If unit > 10000 Then
        unitTh = unitTh + 10
    End If
    unitHu = Fix((unit - unitTh * 1000) / 100)

    locationstring = locationstring & unitTh & "000-" & unitTh & "999\"
    locationstring = locationstring & unitTh & unitHu & "00"
    locationstring = locationstring & "\" & unit & "\"

End If
Exists = (CheckPath(locationstring))
Dim x
If Exists Then
    x = Shell("c:\windows\explorer.exe " & locationstring, vbNormalFocus)
Else
    MsgBox ("Folder does not exist")
End If

End Sub
```